# Error while building python docker container with uWSGI

Tags: python, docker, uwsgi, wsgi

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine


RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN apk --update add gcc build-base freetype-dev libpng-dev openblas-dev musl-dev
RUN apk update

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["uwsgi", "app.ini"]
```

When building uwsgi wheel got and error:

```
In file included from core/utils.c:1:
  ./uwsgi.h:238:10: fatal error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
    238 | #include <linux/limits.h>
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What package am i need to add to Dockerfile?+

Comment: On https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/, select "Contents" at the top, enter `limits.h` as the filename, and `**/linux` as the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `apk add linux-headers`, looks like uwsgi is missing some headers during the build, might be due to alpine being very bare-bones

Answer (score 0):

I also ran in the situation that the container was not building the uwsgi.
After changing
*"FROM python:3.8-alpine" to "FROM python:3.8"*
everything worked fine.
Then i think you also don't need to install the linux-packages.

Comment: This is only working because when you change the base image, you're going from Alpine to Debian. The answer to this should not be "...use a different OS..."